# How to color particular variable value in the email body in powershell script

Tags: powershell, email

I am using the following Powershell script to send the mail

```
$smtpServer ="111.11.1.1.11"
$smtp = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer)
$msg=new-object Net.Mail.MailMessage
$msg.From="noreply@x.com"
$msg.To.Add("x@x.com")
$Success  = $passed/$total*100;
$Failed = $Total- $Passed;
$msg.Subject = "BVT On Build"+$Buildno+",Total :"+ $Total+"  Passed :"+ 
$Passed+"  Failed :"+$Failed+"" #$subject
$msg.Body = "This is an autogenerated mail from  VM - Total Tests Run 
:"+$Total+" `n`n Total Tests Passed :"+ $Passed+" `n`n Pass Percentage 
:"+$Success+" `n`n Failed test cases 'n'n"+$Failed+""
$smtp.Send($msg)
```

My requirement here is to color particular variable value(For example: $Failed in $msg.Body ) in the email body.How can i achieve this?.Could you please help

I know following method but it is used only in the write-host
    `Write-Host $myVariable -ForegroundColor 'Red'`

My output should be like this
This is an autogenerated mail from  VM - Total Tests Run 12
Total Tests Passed : 6
Pass Percentage : 50%
Failed test cases : 6(in red color)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use `HTML` formatting for coloring elements in email body. 
Simple `IF/ELSE` conditional expression to set desired color. Also, you must set `IsBodyHtml` property to `True` so the mail body will not be plain text.

```
$smtpServer ="111.11.1.1.11"
$smtp = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer)
$msg=new-object Net.Mail.MailMessage
$msg.From="noreply@x.com"
$msg.To.Add("x@x.com")
$Success = $passed/$total*100

$SuccessFormatted  = if ($Success -ge 50){
                       '<font color="green">{0}</font>' -f $Success
                     }
                     else{
                       '<font color="red">{0}</font>' -f $Success
                     }

$Failed = $Total- $Passed;
$msg.Subject = "BVT On Build"+$Buildno+",Total :"+ $Total+"  Passed :"+ 
$Passed+"  Failed :"+$Failed+"" #$subject
$msg.Body = "This is an autogenerated mail from  VM - Total Tests Run 
:"+$Total+" `n`n Total Tests Passed :"+ $Passed+" `n`n Pass Percentage 
:"+$SuccessFormatted+" `n`n Failed test cases 'n'n"+$Failed+""

$msg.IsBodyHtml = $true

$smtp.Send($msg)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ..this is what i am looking for.